Finding the full path of the library loaded by LuaJIT `ffi.load`
I am using LuaJIT to open a BLAS library on macOS
-- load.lua
local ffi = require("ffi")
local blas = ffi.load("blas")

I can call procedures like blas.cblas_dgemm and get the correct result, but there are multiple implementations for BLAS.
In particular, both OpenBLAS and the BLAS implementation from the Accelerate framework are installed on my system, so I want to check which one I'm using.
The blas variable returned by ffi.load is a userdata, so I'm not sure how to parse it. I also tried using dtruss, since LuaJIT must stat or open the library at some point. However, all relevant system calls return -1 Err#2.
$ sudo dtruss luajit load.lua 2>&1 | grep blas
read_nocancel(0x3, "local ffi = require(\"ffi\")\nlocal blas = ffi.load(\"blas\")\n\0", 0x1000)     = 57 0
open("libblas.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("libblas.dylib\0", 0x7FF7B459B060, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibblas.dylib\0", 0x7FF7B459B020, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2

How do I get the full path to the dynamic library loaded by ffi.load("blas")?

As a bonus question, is the Accelerate framework on my system broken?
$ file /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib: broken symbolic link to Versions/Current/libBLAS.dylib


Try sudo dtruss sudo -u YOUR_USER_NAME luajit load.lua
